# React Native: Could not create a service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory()

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am trying to build my React Native (0.61.5) solution, but when I am trying to run the below commands:

```
cd && ./gradlew assembleDebug
cd && ./gradlew clean
```

I get the following error:

> Could not create a service of type `ScriptPluginFactory` using
>   `BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory()`.
>
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using 
>   `BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter()`.

**Gradle Version : 5.5**

Could you please advise me?

Comment: Did you check JAVA_HOME?

Comment: /Library/Java/Home is the current path